# Wordpress theme folder inside jquery string?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I want to pass the variable as a php that echoes a Wordpress theme directory url, and I have the following piece of code:

```
var templateUrl = "<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>";
```

and

```
$(".nav").before("<img alt=\"The x logo\" src="+templateUrl+"\"/icon/logo.svg\">");
```

The src I get is something like this:

```
http://x.com/%3C?php...
```

Meaning it just echoes my php, instead of parsing the data and echoing something like the-theme-url/images/etc

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the file extension type of the file with `var templateUrl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
wp_register_script( 'my-url-script', 'myscript_url' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-url-script' );
$translation_array = array( 'templatedir' => get_template_directory() );
//after wp_enqueue_script
wp_localize_script( 'my-url-script', 'object_name', $translation_array );
```

and

```
    var templateUrl = object_name.templatedir;
    $(".nav").before("<img alt=\"The x logo\" src="+templateUrl+"\"/icon/logo.svg\">");
```

Refe:https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89791/theme-path-in-javascript-file

Enjoy..!